# Passive Ethernet-over-coax converters... how do they work?

Tags: ethernet, converter, coax, how-does-it-work

I just bought a pair of [these passive ethernet-over-coax converters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083SCXN22).  I was very skeptical, but they actually work!  I just can't figure out how... they do not require external power, coax only has one pair of conductors (inner wire and outer shield) and ethernet needs at least 2 pairs.  I hate to break them open - was hoping someone could point me to a whitepaper or other technical docs to describe the process.

I can't see any way around some sort of microcontroller that multiplexes the upstream/downstream channels onto the single coax pair, but where is it getting its power? I wasn't aware Ethernet (without PoE) could supply enough power to operate a mcu, but [maybe](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43734/what-is-the-voltage-used-in-ethernet-lines-utp-cables)?

Another thought: if ethernet transmits and receives at **different** frequencies, a couple of tight bandpass filters would allow multiplexing both signals onto the same coax pair and breaking them out on the other end. This would be a completely passive circuit requiring no power.

Thanks for shedding any light on this.

Comment: This says it requires something connected via "poe active coax adapters". I'm not sure what that is, but that sounds like some kind of power over ethernet injector to me.

Comment: @jsotola no you are mistaken. I know what you're referring to, but these are actually ethernet extenders using coax cable.

Comment: @hearth I just tested and they do not require poe or any other power to work. I connected my laptop through these to my ethernet switch and was connected at 100mbps.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ethernet; is there a single-pair mode that they could be using? I know that gigabit and up requires all four pairs, but there may be some mode that just uses a single pair, and then just use a balun to send that over coax instead of twisted pair...

Comment: @hearth I'm not aware of such a mode but it's possible. You'd think it would drop to 10mbps though... Which it didn't. The nic reports connected at 100mbps and my speeds and latencies were within reason.

Comment: @heath looks like single pair ethernet is a new emerging thing... Not yet standardized. https://www.belden.com/blogs/single-pair-ethernet so I don't think that's how they're doing it.

Comment: You talk about transmit and receive at different frequencies--but that can't work, because ethernet (in its modern twisted-pair form, not the older coaxial forms) is baseband signalling. It's not mixed up to a higher frequency for transmission.

Comment: Could you take a look whether your laptop runs this connection in half duplex or full duplex mode?

Comment: @hearth ok... So that possibility is out then.

Comment: What if it just uses a hybrid like how telephones are able to have transmit and receive over a single pair of wires?

Comment: @jonathan s according to powershell get-networkadapter it is operating in full duplex mode. (full duplex == true)

Comment: One of the Amazon comments says that only 3 pins of the RJ45 are wired. So only a single pair. Also the description says Balun in the title. Another commenter said they were running at 7 Mbps. That means 10 is probably the fallback if the hardware can't do a better single pair mode??

Comment: @tobalt I downloaded at 45mbps and uploaded at 12, my internet's max speeds. Latency differences were unappreciable.

Comment: 10-base-T 10Mbps and 100-base-T 100Mbps use two unidtrectional pairs, there's no single pair mode. 10-base-2 uses a single coax bus, but is half-duplex. I am not aware of any passive 10-base-2 to 10-base-T media converters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a [hybrid transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_coil) for the ethernet and a [bias tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_tee) for the power in there

Comment: Thanks, those are interesting components that I didn't know about! Learning!

Comment: So with this setup, what are the downsides? Why not just design all ethernet this way and reduce the number of conductors needed?

Comment: the main disadvantage is that coaxial cable is more expensive than twisted pair (unless you already have coaxial cable installed)

Comment: Also curious: how much wattage is available in the ethernet signal itself (not PoE )? Could a bias tee extract a DC signal with enough power to operate a MCU?

Comment: the signal is 3V, 3V into 100 ohms is 90mW and you will loose half of the power in the dummy load at each end (if using the hybrid transformers), there is no power when the terminal is not sending.

Comment: @RyanGriggs Are you really asking for the downsides of coax vs cat5 ? All of them. The fact that only two conductors are needed is not even an advantage: coax is more expensive to produce. There is much more copper on coax. Cable is more stiffy. Connectors are more expensive. Cabling is error prone. And of course the main disadvantage is that adding a new node on an existing net requires disconnecting all nodes. 20 years ago, coax was still used in cheap setups because no switch/hubs were required. Nowadays, you can buy a switch for the price of two 50 ohm terminators. Why would you want coax?

Comment: @dim, you missed the point. I was simply asking why not use hybrid transformers and then only need 2 conductors instead of 8.

Comment: Single pair etherenet is a thing, but it seems to have mainly industrial applications (also perhaps it's used in HDMI?)